# В IE11 Некорректно определяется высота текста при переносе

Tags: html, css

Столкнулась с некорректной работой старых браузеров.

В IE 11  в определенных условиях (если текст в блоке достаточно длинный ) переносимый текст накладывается на  нижележащий блок.
Это хорошо заметно если уменьшать размер окна. (та же проблема в chrome 35).
Пример внизу. Как с этим бороться?

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  border: unset solid #808080;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.scrollArea {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 5px black;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body style="padding:0px;margin:0px" class="container">


  <div class="wrap">
    <div style="display:block;">

      <h1>
        это сообщение текстового блока это сообщение текстового блока это сообщение текстового блока это сообщение текстового блокаэто сообщение текстового блока
      </h1>
      <div>s</div>

    </div>
    <div id="scroll" class="scrollArea"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ну а зачем у вас для `div class="scrollArea"` дано `height:100%`? Он просто пытается занять всю доступную высоту.

Comment: В новых браузерах все работает. Очень хорошо видно если изменять ;line-height: при значении 1 смещение незначительное А  ecли установить 3 например, то высота блока верхней части не поменяется, а текст залезет вниз.

Comment: Да Большое спасибо  убрала height Все  заработало. Вообще этот атрибут в данном случае должен игнорироваться согласно спецификации